# Untappable CollectionViewCells Which Overlaps Header [Swift]

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

[image]

As described on title, actually I have problems about tap area . What I have done is to overlap the cells with header by using `SectionInset` from custom `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` so it looks like as stated on image.

The problem is, as you can see red circle and green circle there, it represents cannot be tapped and can be tapped. I have search over for whole day and I found the answer with no avail.

Is there anything that I have missed?

The cell insets code in `ViewDidLoad`:

```
let layout: FlowLayoutProperty = FlowLayoutProperty.init(itemSize: CGSize.zero, minimumInteritemSpacing: 10, minimumLineSpacing: 10)
        layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionView.ScrollDirection.vertical
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets.init(top: -50, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
```

The header code is:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    
    //header height size, refer headerreferencesize
    
    switch kind {
        case UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader:
            
            guard let headerView: V4UMGCMainHeader = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "V4UMGCMainHeaderWeather", for: indexPath) as? V4UMGCMainHeader else {
                fatalError("Header not found")
            }
            
            self.headerView = headerView
            
            let dFormat: DateFormatter = DateFormatter.init()
            dFormat.dateFormat = "EE, dd MMM"
            headerView.lblUMGCWDate.text = dFormat.string(from: Date.init())
            
            headerView.btnUMGCWAddMember.transformToContentStandard()
            headerView.btnUMGCWAddMember.titleLabel?.font = FontPredefine.MuliMedium(withSize: 12.0)
            headerView.btnUMGCWAddMember.backgroundColor = UIColor.hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#C18845")
            headerView.btnUMGCWAddMember.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.checkMemberShipHeader(sender:)), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)
            
            headerView.lblUMGCWLocation.text = "Point Location"
            
            if(KeychainedLoginCache.loadClubMemberInfo()[.ClubHouseID]! == nil && self.menuType == MenuType.UserMode)
            {
                //if clubmember not available
                headerView.btnUMGCWAddMember.setTitle(AppDelegate.getLocalString(forKey: "UMGCVC_CLUBHEADER_ADDMEMBER_BTN"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
                headerView.btnUMGCWAddMember.isEnabled = true
                headerView.lcUMGCWAddMemberHeight.constant = 40
                self.headerLayoutProperty?.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets.init(top: -50, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
            }
            else
            {
                //if clubmember available
                headerView.btnUMGCWAddMember.setTitle("", for: UIControl.State.normal)
                headerView.btnUMGCWAddMember.isEnabled = false
                headerView.lcUMGCWAddMemberHeight.constant = 0
                self.headerLayoutProperty?.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets.init(top: -90, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
            }
       
            
        return headerView
        
    default:
        assert(false, "error")
        
    }
    return V4UMGCMainHeader.init()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think this is really tricky. I should put `zIndex` on `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` under `layoutAttributesForElements` and `layoutAttributesForItem`, now it works.